# Reference for xgboost

Tags: machine-learning, references, boosting

The xgboost package and the algorithm behind it are often mentioned in data science competitions. The method is called extreme gradient boosting. I would like to learn how it differs from typical gradient boosting, but I can not find a rigorous reference for its theoretical basis on the Web. What is the right reference for xgboost?

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer referring to the xgboost paper, since it is the authoritative source for xgboost information.

Comment: @Sycorax you mean the newer answer?

Comment: That's the one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Source:  [Tianqi Chen's Quora answer](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-the-R-gbm-gradient-boosting-machine-and-xgboost-extreme-gradient-boosting)

> Both xgboost and gbm follows the principle of gradient boosting. 
>   There are however, the difference in modeling details. Specifically, 
>   xgboost used a more regularized model formalization to control
>   over-fitting, which gives it better performance.
>
> We have updated a comprehensive tutorial on introduction to the model,
>   which you might want to take a look at. [Introduction to Boosted Trees](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/model.html)
>
> The name xgboost, though, actually refers to the engineering goal to
>   push the limit of computations resources for boosted tree algorithms.
>   Which is the reason why many people use xgboost. For model, it might
>   be more suitable to be called as regularized gradient boosting.

Comment: Right .. this sees to be it .. I though he had written a paper about it but the regularization seems to be the key ... at least I understaood that ;) Thanks!

Comment: @Richard Glad that it helped.  Those [docs](http://xgboost.readthedocs.org/en/latest/model.html) are really good, atleast for understanding the concept and code up some basic examples.

Comment: @Richard Actually we do have a paper: http://jmlr.org/proceedings/papers/v42/chen14.pdf

Answer (score 6):

There is now an arXiv article [XGBoost: A Scalable Tree Boosting System](https://dx.doi.org/10.1145/2939672.2939785) that describes the algorithm. At the time of the original question and answer this had not yet been posted.